# Need to put all the three tables in one page

Tags: tables

I am asked to put all the three tables in a single page. As a beginner, I do not have enough expertise to do it. In MS Word, I could have three textbox side by side but here I do not know how to do it. We can reduce the number of rows(records) to make them identical, if required. Please help.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Important
% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%Table packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
% Title
\title{Problem with table settings}
\author{Some author}
\date{Drafted:\today}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Design and implementation}\label{Design and implementation}
% For tables use
\begin{table}[!htb]
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Calculation of individual node stability}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c| c c c c}
\toprule
\thead{Node} &\thead{ \% of energy} & \thead{Activeness}& \thead{Mobility}& \thead{Stability}\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{A} & 95 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{B} & 58 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{C} & 66 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{D} & 72 & 0.7 &0.25 &0.257\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{E} & 65 & 0.7 &0.40 &0.212\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{F} & 86 & 0.9 &0.02 &0.426\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{G} & 55 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{H} & 62 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{I} & 73 & 0.7 &0.02 &0.326\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{J} & 90 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
\addlinespace
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
% For tables use
\begin{table}[!htb]
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Determination of immediate neighbours}
\label{tab:2}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\toprule
\thead{Node} &\thead{Immediate neighbours} & \thead{ }& \thead{ }& \thead{ }\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{A} & C & D & E & H\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{B} & D &  &  & \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{C} & A & E & G & \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{D} & A & B &  & \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{E} & A & C & F & G\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{F} & E & H & I & J\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{G} & C & E & I & \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{H} & A & F & J & \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{I} & F & G & J & \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{J} & F & H & I & \\
\addlinespace
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

%Table 3
\begin{table}[!htb]
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Determination of link stability}
\label{tab:3}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
\thead{Node pair} &\thead{Calculated stability}\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{(A,H)} & 0.37 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(A,E)} & 0.32 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(A,D)} & 0.34 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(A,C)} & 0.38 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(B,D)} & 0.29 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(C,G)} & 0.32 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(C,E)} & 0.27 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(E,F)} & 0.32 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(E,G)} & 0.27 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(F,H)} & 0.37 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(F,I)} & 0.38 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(F,J)} & 0.43 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(G,I)} & 0.32 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(H,J)} & 0.37 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(I,J)} & 0.38 \\
\addlinespace
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The class file can be downloaded from [documentclass](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IY8O0kSP1Vn8svvr8hTDZLlV8XoFTMMB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I doubt all three tables will fit side by side into the available space without at least some kind of adjustment.

Comment: We can put two of them side by side and one below. The requirement is to put all of them in one page. We can also drop a few records to reduce the length (last option though).

Comment: Do columns 3 to 5 in the second column also contain a column header?

Comment: Which table? The last two columns of the second table has a common heading " Immediate neighbours". But I could not control it to behave like a merged header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like the following helps you getting started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Design and implementation}\label{Design and implementation}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.425\linewidth}
\caption{Calculation of individual node stability}
\label{tab:1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\toprule
\thead{Node} &\thead{ \% of\\ energy} & \thead{Activeness}& \thead{Mobility}& \thead{Stability}\\
\midrule
\textbf{A} & 95 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
\textbf{B} & 58 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
\textbf{C} & 66 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
\textbf{D} & 72 & 0.7 &0.25 &0.257\\
\textbf{E} & 65 & 0.7 &0.40 &0.212\\ \addlinespace
\textbf{F} & 86 & 0.9 &0.02 &0.426\\
\textbf{G} & 55 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
\textbf{H} & 62 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
\textbf{I} & 73 & 0.7 &0.02 &0.326\\
\textbf{J} & 90 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\caption{Determination of immediate neighbours}
\label{tab:2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c *{4}{wc{1.25em}}}
\toprule
\thead{Node} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Immediate\\ neighbours}}\\
\midrule
\textbf{A} & C & D & E & H\\
\textbf{B} & D &  &  & \\
\textbf{C} & A & E & G & \\
\textbf{D} & A & B &  & \\
\textbf{E} & A & C & F & G\\ \addlinespace
\textbf{F} & E & H & I & J\\
\textbf{G} & C & E & I & \\
\textbf{H} & A & F & J & \\
\textbf{I} & F & G & J & \\
\textbf{J} & F & H & I & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\caption{Determination of link stability}
\label{tab:3}
\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
\toprule
\thead[l]{Node\\ pair} & \textbf{(A,H)} & \textbf{(A,E)} & \textbf{(A,D)} & \textbf{(A,C)} & \textbf{(B,D)} &  \textbf{(C,G)} & \textbf{(C,E)}  &  \textbf{(E,F)}\\
\thead[l]{Calculated\\ stability} & 0.37 & 0.32 & 0.34 & 0.38 & 0.29 & 0.32 & 0.27 & 0.32 \\ \midrule
\thead[l]{Node\\ pair} & \textbf{(E,G)} & \textbf{(F,H)} & \textbf{(F,I)}  & \textbf{(F,J)} & \textbf{(G,I)} & \textbf{(H,J)} & \textbf{(I,J)}  \\
\thead[l]{Calculated\\ stability} &  0.27 & 0.37 & 0.38 & 0.43 & 0.32 & 0.37 & 0.38 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Table 2 is overlapping with table 1. If you download the shared class from my OP, you can reproduce it. Table 3 is fine. Is it possible to keep table 1 and 2 side by side and table 3 below or table 1 on top and table 2 and 3 side by side(I mean whichever looks ok)?  If required 2-3 records may be chopped off from any table.

Comment: Would combining table 1 and table 2 into one table be an option? You could remove the repeated first column with this approach.

Comment: No, unfortunately the tables are distinct.

Comment: @Bukaida: What about https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mqZ7.png?

Comment: Excellent, trying this immediately :)

Comment: Have you modified your OP?

Comment: It is leaving a big blank space on the top, otherwise it is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Your tables are to wide that can be in one row, so to my opinion a possible solution is to have first two table in the first row, and third table in the second, but all tables in the same float `table`:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[center]{caption}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
 
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}

% Title
\title{Problem with table settings}
\author{Some author}
\date{Drafted:\today}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\section{Design and implementation}\label{Design and implementation}
% For tables use
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
    \centering
% table caption is above the table
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\caption{Calculation of individual node stability}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c c c c c}
    \toprule
\thead{Node} &\thead{ \%\\ of energy} & \thead{Activeness} & \thead{Mobility}& \thead{Stability}\\
    \midrule
A & 95 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
B & 58 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
C & 66 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
D & 72 & 0.7 &0.25 &0.257\\
E & 65 & 0.7 &0.40 &0.212\\
F & 86 & 0.9 &0.02 &0.426\\
G & 55 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
H & 62 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
I & 73 & 0.7 &0.02 &0.326\\
J & 90 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\caption{Determination of immediate neighbours}
\label{tab:2}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c c c c c}
\toprule
\thead{Node} &\thead{Immediate\\ neighbours} &  & &     \\
    \midrule
A & C & D & E & H\\
B & D &  &  & \\
C & A & E & G & \\
D & A & B &  & \\
E & A & C & F & G\\
F & E & H & I & J\\
G & C & E & I & \\
H & A & F & J & \\
I & F & G & J & \\
J & F & H & I & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}


%Table 3
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\caption{Determination of link stability}
\label{tab:3}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{>{\bfseries}c c}
    \toprule
\thead{Node\\ pair} &\thead{Calculated\\ stability}\\
    \midrule 
(A,H)   & 0.37 \\
(A,E)   & 0.32 \\
(A,D)   & 0.34 \\
(A,C)   & 0.38 \\
(B,D)   & 0.29 \\
(C,G)   & 0.32 \\
(C,E)   & 0.27 \\
(E,F)   & 0.32 \\
(E,G)   & 0.27 \\
(F,H)   & 0.37 \\
(F,I)   & 0.38 \\
(F,J)   & 0.43 \\
(G,I)   & 0.32 \\
(H,J)   & 0.37 \\
(I,J)   & 0.38 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate paelayout)

Note, I a wee bit cleanup your tables  code.

Comment: \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}    These two are showing error "command undefined" even after installing the package "showframe". If I comment these two lines, the entire document template is becoming a mess. How to get rid of it?

Comment: @Bukaida, this part of MWE is not essential for you, it just draw page layout (which in real document should be removed from its preamble). I remove it already now (consequently you with compilation of MWE in answer will not see red lines indicating page layout anymore. Now compilation of MWE should go smooth, without any error. Error probably has been arise because you have not loaded `color` package

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `minipage` environment within a single `table` environment. However, as three tables couldn't adjust side by side without overlapping, I decreased the left and right margins of the particular page using the `newgeometry` command from the geometry package. Also, I made some changes in the column names to increase readability.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Important
% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%Table packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
% Title
\title{Problem with table settings}
\author{Some author}
\date{Drafted:\today}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm} %%%%% addition - to change the margin of the specific page
\section{Design and implementation}\label{Design and implementation}
% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \caption{Calculation of individual node stability}
    \label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
    % For LaTeX tables use
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c| c c c c}
    \toprule
    \thead{Node} &\thead{ \% of energy} & \thead{Activeness}& \thead{Mobility}& \thead{Stability}\\
    \midrule\\
    \textbf{A} & 95 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{B} & 58 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{C} & 66 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{D} & 72 & 0.7 &0.25 &0.257\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{E} & 65 & 0.7 &0.40 &0.212\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{F} & 86 & 0.9 &0.02 &0.426\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{G} & 55 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{H} & 62 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{I} & 73 & 0.7 &0.02 &0.326\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{J} & 90 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
    \addlinespace
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill %%%% addition
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \caption{Determination of immediate neighbours}
    \label{tab:2}       % Give a unique label
    % For LaTeX tables use
    \begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    \toprule
    \thead{Node} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Immediate\\ neighbours}}\\
    \midrule\\
    \textbf{A} & C & D & E & H\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{B} & D &  &  & \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{C} & A & E & G & \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{D} & A & B &  & \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{E} & A & C & F & G\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{F} & E & H & I & J\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{G} & C & E & I & \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{H} & A & F & J & \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{I} & F & G & J & \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{J} & F & H & I & \\
    \addlinespace
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
% table caption is above the table
\hfill %%%% addition
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
    %Table 3
    % table caption is above the table
    \caption{Determination of link stability}
    \label{tab:3}       % Give a unique label
    % For LaTeX tables use
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
    \toprule
    \thead{Node pair} &\thead{Calculated\\ stability}\\
    \midrule\\
    \textbf{(A,H)} & 0.37 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(A,E)} & 0.32 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(A,D)} & 0.34 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(A,C)} & 0.38 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(B,D)} & 0.29 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(C,G)} & 0.32 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(C,E)} & 0.27 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(E,F)} & 0.32 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(E,G)} & 0.27 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(F,H)} & 0.37 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(F,I)} & 0.38 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(F,J)} & 0.43 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(G,I)} & 0.32 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(H,J)} & 0.37 \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{(I,J)} & 0.38 \\
    \addlinespace
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\restoregeometry %%%% addition - restore default margin
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image: output]

Wish this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a slightly different layout, obtained with the `floatrow` package, and a third table with 4 columns. I also replaced the repeated use of `\addlinespace` with the `\makegapedcells` command from `makecell`.

```
 \documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Important
% Math packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%Table packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
% Title
\title{Problem with table settings}
\author{Some author}
\date{Drafted:\today}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Design and implementation}\label{Design and implementation}
% For tables use
\begin{table}[!htb]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
 \centering
 \ttabbox{\caption{Calculation of individual node stability}
 \label{tab:1}}% Give a unique label
 {\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c| c c c c}
 \toprule
 \thead{Node} &\thead{ \% of \\ energy} & \thead{Activeness}& \thead{Mobility}& \thead{Stability}\\
 \midrule\\
 A & 95 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\
 B & 58 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
 C & 66 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
 D & 72 & 0.7 &0.25 &0.257\\
 E & 65 & 0.7 &0.40 &0.212\\
 F & 86 & 0.9 &0.02 &0.426\\
 G & 55 & 0.7 &0.03 &0.323\\
 H & 62 & 0.7 &0.05 &0.317\\
 I & 73 & 0.7 &0.02 &0.326\\
 J & 90 & 0.9 &0.01 &0.429\\[\smallskipamount]
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}}
\vskip 4ex

\begin{floatrow}
\centering
\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
\ttabbox{\caption{Determination of immediate neighbours}
\label{tab:2}}% Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
{\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c c c c c}
\toprule
\thead{Node} &\thead{Immediate\\ neighbours} \\
\midrule\\
A & C & D & E & H\\
B & D & & & \\
C & A & E & G & \\
D & A & B & & \\
E & A & C & F & G\\
F & E & H & I & J\\
G & C & E & I & \\
H & A & F & J & \\
I & F & G & J & \\
J & F & H & I & \\[\smallskipamount]
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}}
%Table 3
\ttabbox{%
\caption{Determination of link stability}
\label{tab:3} }% Give a unique label
{\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c c >{\bfseries}c c}
\toprule
\thead{Node pair} &\thead{Calculated\\ stability} & \thead{Node pair} &\thead{Calculated\\ stability} \\
\midrule\\
\textbf{(A,H)} & 0.37 & (E,G) & 0.27 \\
\textbf{(A,E)} & 0.32 & (F,H) & 0.37 \\
\textbf{(A,D)} & 0.34 & (F,I) & 0.38 \\
\textbf{(A,C)} & 0.38 & (F,J) & 0.43 \\
\textbf{(B,D)} & 0.29 & (G,I) & 0.32 \\
\textbf{(C,G)} & 0.32 & (H,J) & 0.37 \\
\textbf{(C,E)} & 0.27 & (I,J) & 0.38 \\
\textbf{(E,F)} & 0.32 \\[\smallskipamount]%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]